# Error while generating a c++ project on unreal engine 5.3

Tags: c++, unreal

When I try to create a C++ proeject in unreal engine 5.3 it shows an error printing this message

An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.3/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/Arno/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject8/MyProject8.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
CreateProc failed: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x00000002)
URL: C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.3/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/Arno/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject8/MyProject8.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Couldn't create process 'C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.3/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat'
```

I expected to create a new C++ project in unreal it is create blueprint projects without any error but cannot create a c++ project file

Comment: Regarding the path `C:/Users/Arno/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject8`, I've had so much pain caused by spaces in file paths that A) I don't allow them and B) immediately suspect that they're the cause of the problem. So, first thing I'd do is get rid of the <expletive deleted>ing space.

Comment: it happens even if I change the directory